# strange .net MVC Form Authentication,it redirect to login when client request css/js file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Another web site using iframe to access my `Product/List` Page in my mvc project. my page includes some css and js tag.In my mvc project, I am using SSO(Single Sign On). When another web site request my page firstly, I will redirect to `Authentication.Web/SignIn.aspx`. After the user is authenticated, it will redirect back to my `Account/Login?ticket=abcd&returnUrl=Product%2fList`. Finally it redirect to Product/List.

After the client receive the response of `Product/List`, it start to download `css/js` file. And then some stange thing happened. The mvc authentication module redirect the request to `CmsSystem.Web/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fCmsSystem.Web%2fContent%2fCmsSite.css`.

This problem is only **happend in IE**, and it is normal in firefox and chrome.So I think my program logic is no problem. I use fiddler tool to capture the request like this:

---

```
1./CmsSystem.Web/Product/List
2./CmsSystem.Web/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fProduct%2fList
3.Authentication.Web/SignIn.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fProduct%2fList
4./CmsSystem.Web/Account/Login?ticket=abcd&ReturnUrl=%2fProduct%2fList
5./CmsSystem.Web/Product/List
6./CmsSystem.Web/Content/CmsSite.css
7./CmsSystem.Web/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
8./CmsSystem.Web/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fContent%2fCmsSite.css
9./CmsSystem.Web/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.9.1.js
```

---

my web.config as below:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="CmsSystem.LogUser" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

---

I found the authentication cookie is send to client in step 4. Is is sent to server from client from step 5 to step 9.The response of the `Product/List` page is received in client in step 5. Why mvc redirect to Account/Login in step 8 and step 9 when client request css/js file?   Besides css/js file, I also need to post ajax request after document.ready(). And mvc also redirect to the Account/login.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try setting the access rights for your CSS and JS directoeries to use Anonymous access in web.config??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing access to my Site.Css on my login form MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383242/allowing-access-to-my-site-css-on-my-login-form-mvc)

Comment: thank you Nilesh! It is works using authorization in webconfig for css/js file. However, After my html document loaded, i need to post an ajax request.When request is sended with Authenticated cookie to server, mvc always redirect to login!! In addition, i think there is some abnormal thing in my applicaion.

Comment: thank you Rajesh! your suggestion can fix the problem of accessing the css/js file. but i need to send ajax post request after the html page loaded. Can I override mvc authenticate module to contorl whether redirect or not.

Comment: Can you post the code of your route configuration? Are you making use of bundles for your css/js? [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: I just got my app in this state. It must be something with file permissions. Since I packed than unpacked web app in same directory under same name. Before it was working and then I had to restore old version which caused this behavior. I am inspecting atm. I hope I will have answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, it is because i set the chinese character in the cookie. and then it caused some problems in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

For me packing and unpacking files with IzArc corrupted permission for "Authenticated Users" it was displaying Unknown User instead. Re-adding permission to "Authenticated users" solved the problem.

I had old folder available so I was able to compare. This was my case and I am posting it here knowing that it may not be an answer to this specific situation. This clearly fixed it for me.