# redirect to error page if accessing Content, CSS, and JS files and

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I forbid the access to Content, CSS, and JS files by disabling directory browsing. Now if i type url

https://xxxx:443/ceqr/Content/ I get the page in image below

[image: Error Page]

What i want is to redirect user to https://xxxx:443/ceqr/ErrorPage/  if trying to access https://xxxx:443/ceqr/Content/

I have tried a few thing Like using Filter but since Content is not part of the Controller that does not work

Having location in web config does not either.

it does not get caught in Application_Error in golbal.ascx.cs.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383242/allowing-access-to-my-site-css-on-my-login-form-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config file you could put this section.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/PageForbidden" />
   </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

and you will create a Controller which has the name `Error` and the `PageForbidden` action like the following

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PageForbidden()
    {
       Response.StatusCode = 403;
       return View();
    }
}
```

and also you should has a view with the name 'PageForbidden'

Comment: Thanks You Hakam Fostok

Comment: glad that this help you

Answer (score 1):

So IIS is handling that error, it hasn't got to the application yet.  For this type of error, you'll want to configure [HttpErrors](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) in your web.config.  For application level errors, use [CustomErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx).